# Object must be linked but can't delete it

Tags: modeling, objects, geometry, linked-data

I haven't been modeling long and completely fubar'ed my model so i had to go in a clean it up but i can't seem to to get rid of this one piece. I tried unlinking, didn't work & if i try to just delete it, it deletes a huge chunk of the model. It's driving me nuts because i don't need or want this piece there..I don't want to put the rest together until i can get this piece outta there lol.[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that when  i do try to unlink it, it says "not yet implemented" in yellow at the bottom of the screen. There has to be a way for me to remove this piece. If i try to unlink selecting the main body then the main body itself gets deleted, but when i try to delete the secondary piece it gives me the error mentioned above.

Comment: Hello :). It seems that both those parts are actually one object. Switch to Edit mode and delete all unwanted faces/vertices.